# MongoDB query optimization

Tags: mongodb

as my current task I have to optimize the indexes so that some of our queries run faster. I read this article: http://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/
as this guys suggests My optimal query is when:

```
 nscanned= nscannedObject = n
```

Well, I was able to achieve that. The problem however that the query satisfying this formula is slower than the one does not ! 
Here is my explain output :

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor previous_sticky_1",
    "nscanned" : 65019,
    "nscannedObjects" : 65019,
    "n" : 65019,
    "millis" : 5456,
    "nYields" : 76,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
}//everything is ok ( nscanned= nscannedObject = n ) 



  {
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor subnetInfo.giAddr_1",
"nscanned" : 65023,
"nscannedObjects" : 65023,
"n" : 65019,
"scanAndOrder" : true,
"millis" : 3355,
"nYields" : 37,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"isMultiKey" : false,
"indexOnly" : false
```

}
// nscanned = nscannedObject > n but , "millis = 3355 < 5456 " ???

Can you guys suggest why is that ? and which index to use ?  subnetInfo.giAddr_1 or previous_sticky_1 ?

Comment: Can you show us the query and a sample document?

Comment: I am not sure but I think It is confident info, sorry.

Comment: x it all out, we just need to see the document structure

Comment: No one can help you before will not see your document and the query.

Comment: Well, may be someone has some assumption ?

Comment: Taking orid's answer have you tried running this query multiple times on different system load and hot/cold sets? Have you made sure those explains are consistent? Other than that, we cannoty hit a bulleyes with a blind fold on

Comment: Not yet, but I will as soon as I get free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try several executions of your query using both hints and calculate the average time it takes. Your results may have to do with the fact that during your first execution, index files had to be paged into resident memory. [Use touch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) to eliminate this effect.

Your indexes metrics are similar, so I don't expect any big difference using one or the other. What may be more relevant, which you haven't mentioned is the fields you use in indexes.

Comment: Yields is when the data is not in RAM, it doesn't mean there *were* write operations